# rsync gives an error in shell script

Tags: centos, rsync

I have a script that copy files to another server. I don't want to overwrite any files so I have to use rsync.

I can use rsync without any problem when I run at command line.
But when I use it in script, rsync does not work. It gives an error and I even could not find that error at Google.

Here is error:

```
rsync: Failed to exec ssh: Not a directory (20)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(84) [sender=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I would like to point that error is **not** No such file or directory(2)

Error is: **Not a directory(20)**

Here is script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$1
FILE=$2
DAY=$(/usr/bin/date +'%Y-%m-%d')
/usr/bin/rsync -avh $PATH postgres@REMOTE_IP:/Backup/xlog_backup/$DAY/.
```

I am using like this

```
sh ~postgres/archive.sh /srv/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/000000010000003E00000025 000000010000003E00000025
```

Here is ls output:

```
postgres@MY_SERVER:~$ls -l /srv/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/000000010000003E00000025
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 May 25 10:41 /srv/postgresql/data/pg_xlog/000000010000003E00000025
```

> Server: CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
>
> Rsync: rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
>
> postgres@MY_SERVER:~$rpm -qa | grep openssh
>
> openssh-clients-6.6.1p1-22.el7.x86_64
>
> openssh-server-6.6.1p1-22.el7.x86_64
>
> openssh-6.6.1p1-22.el7.x86_64
>
> rsync-3.0.9-17.el7.x86_64

Could you help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use `$PATH` as a variable in your scripts**!!!

It will override your, eh, `$PATH`.

An example:

```
echo $PATH   
/home/maulinglawns/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

If I assign something else to `$PATH`, what happens?

```
maulinglawns@debian-HP:~$ PATH=foo
maulinglawns@debian-HP:~$ echo $PATH
foo
maulinglawns@debian-HP:~$ ls
bash: ls: command not found
```

As a general recommendation, I would suggest to avoid using UPPERCASE only entirely when assigning variables in your scripts. It is better that they are left as reserved for the shell's environment variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed that PATH can be overwritted. Problem is gone now.

Comment: @YavuzSelim No problem. I have made the same mistake (once) in the past. That's how we learn ;-)